# Unable to generate the output difference from String

Tags: python, maya

Firstly, I apologize if my subject title is wrong as I do not know how to phrase it in any better way. I am trying to print out the items that do not contains the word `Shape` in a list but I am unable to get the output at all. It generates something but still it is the wrong one.

In the code below, I have written out the output but as you can see in the last line, instead of generating `"group1", "locator1" and "pCube1"`, it simply generates `pCubeShape1`.

Could someone advice me on this? Many thanks in advance.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

newSel01 = cmds.ls(sl=True)
# [u'group1', u'locator1', u'locatorShape1', u'pCube1', u'pCubeShape1']

if "Shape" in str(newSel01):
    if item in newSel01:
        print item
        # pCubeShape1
```

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand is that you want to filter out all items of the list which do not contain the word "Shape":

```
>>> x = [u'group1', u'locator1', u'locatorShape1', u'pCube1', u'pCubeShape1']
>>> filter(lambda s:  "Shape" not in s, x)                                                                                                                                     
[u'group1', u'locator1', u'pCube1']
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to get the transforms from a selection the `ls` command has a [`transforms`](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2012/en_us/CommandsPython/ls.html#flagtransforms) argument.

```
ls(sl=True, transforms=True)
```

will filter out any shapes.

Alternatively, the [`shapes`](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2012/en_us/CommandsPython/ls.html#flagshapes) argument:

```
ls(sl=True, shapes=True)
```

will do the inverse.

---

That way there is no need for any string comparisons or regex searches. This is mostly an FYI; all the other answers are pretty spot on for doing what you asked.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = [u'group1', u'locator1', u'locatorShape1', u'pCube1', u'pCubeShape1']
>>> result = [ i for i in l if 'Shape' not in i ]
>>> result
[u'group1', u'locator1', u'pCube1']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Try

```
for item in newSel01:
    if "Shape" not in item:
        print item
```

You pick up each entry in the list and check if the string "Shape" does not occur in it and print it. This will of-course print each entry separately. You can append the items to a list or use list comprehension to be more concise.

```
[x for x in newSel01 if "Shape" not in x]
```

You can also use the `filter` approach

```
filter(lambda x: "Shape" not in x, newSel01)
```